# WPF re-size border at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

Does setting a Framework elements (Border in this case) width in XAML prevent me from changing this value at run time?

I have a grid containing a border which in turn contains some other controls. I have an animation which expands the grid and border width and height increasing the values from 0.

I have then placed a button above the border to act as a re-sizing aid (it is a border-less window). here is a snippet of the code that should be re-sizing the border:

```
private void GridResize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        startPoint = this.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
        Mouse.Capture(GridResize);
        Resizing = true;

}

private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (Resizing)
        {
            FrameworkElement border = (FrameworkElement)LibraryBorder;
            //an arbitrary value for testing 
            border.Width += 20;
            LibraryBorder.InvalidateVisual();
        }
}
```

The initial animation sets the borders width to 1500. When debugging both events are being registered and Window_MouseMove is trying to amend the borders width. It does not however alter the value - it remains at 1500. I cast the element to a FrameworkElement in the hope that this would allow me to amend the width property. I assume that my xaml values are somehow overriding my code. Any ideas on how to get around this. I thought I would ask before I go the route of moving all my animations in to code to discover there is a better way ( or that the code approach wont make a difference!!).

Thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: Does your Storyboard have [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) [HoldEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior.aspx) which is default? This would prevent you from changing the width. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing).

Comment: I haven't set these and weren't aware that they were defaults. I will have a look - thanks for the pointer

Comment: If I set FillBehavior to Stop then the animation runs and the values revert back to their original state. Is there a way to release the HoldEnd from code?

Comment: Thanks to LPL - if you put your suggestion as an answer I will accept. It seems need to set my FillBehavior to Stop and then handle the onCompleted event for my double animation that deals with the width property - setting this to the final value and opening the property for editing again.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer. Thanks. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `Storyboard` doesn't have [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) [HoldEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior.aspx) which is default. This would prevent you from changing the width. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing).